# best way to dynamically change the UITableViewCell for the first row only

Tags: ios, swift

I'd like to be able to dynamically change the first cell of my UITableView.

Basically, when I'm scrolling, I'd like the first row to  be "highlighted" when it is scrolled to first visible position in the table. I found at least one way involving

```
indexPathsForVisibleRows
```

and

```
reloadRows at:indexPath:
```

but the results are less than optimal.

Is there a clean way to achieve this?

Comment: why not update it on cell will display?

Comment: because it would not work for cells scrolled to  first position. updated the question to clarify =)

Answer (score 0):

As I understand that you are creating a thing that look like dateTimePicker/Picker. So, I think the implement are the same between these. First, Delegate from scrollView must be handle to know when will the TableView is stopped scrolling. Then, we have to snap to the first cell visible fully visible (in case it just visible a little bit). Then we need to update that first cell to hight light. Hope this will help you.